# Junit 5 : How to provide names to Parameterized Test

Tags: junit5

I have simple parameterized test case like below

```
@ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = { "Hello", "World","Test" })
    void withFixValues(String word) {
        System.out.println(word);
        assertNotNull(word);

    }
```

But in case test fails , it not easy to check for which parameter value test is failing. Is there any way we can name Parameterized test cases based on parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can provide name using name attribute.

```
        @ParameterizedTest(name = "withSomeName #{index} with Value [{arguments}]")
        @ValueSource(strings = { "Hello", "World","Test" })
        void withFixValues(String word) {
            System.out.println(word);
            assertNotNull(word);

        }
```